# How to change tab contents in the app according to a specific page in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have and ionic app which has some pages and 2 tabs page. tab1 is a general tab which is common throughout the app. Tab2 shows specifics contents respect to the contents of a specific page. Now I want to know how to code in such a way that whenever a user goes to a specific page, rather than show tab1 it should show tab2. and when user exists that page it should again show tab1. Right now I am only able to show tab1

```
this is my tab1     
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex" #mytabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"  tabIcon="md-home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="md-chatboxes"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabIcon="md-call"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabIcon="md-settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

this is my tab2
 <ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex" #myheattabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"  tabIcon="md-home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="md-chatboxes"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabIcon="md-alert"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabIcon="md-alert"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

my file.ts
 constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: 
NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public translate: 
TranslateService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController
,public global: Global, public menu: MenuController, public api: 
ApiProvider, public http: HttpClient, public toastCtrl: ToastController) 
{
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.heattabBarElement = document.querySelector('# 
myheattabs.tabbar.show-tabbar')
  }

  //hide tabs 
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
    this.heattabBarElement.style.display = 'block';
    console.log('did eneter');
    this.presentToast2("Please wait while the map is loading");
  }  

  ionViewWillLeave() {   
  this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'flex';
  this.heattabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Right now I am only able to show either tab1 or tab2 throught out the app

Comment: what does this mean... "and when user exists that page it should again show tab1"? when the user exits, it doesn't matter which tab is being displayed, right?

Comment: @Akber it matters. e.g if the the user visits page A then it should show tab2 and when user exits the page and goes back to home page it should show tab1